# How to get liked urls of my website from facebook Graph?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

How can I get urls liked from my website that I have an application for sorted by most liked or get most 10 liked urls from my website please Reply ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use google analytics, subscribe for the edge.create event ( which is fired when someone clicked a like button ) and track that with analytics ...

If you want to know the likes without analytics then you should first get all the links you want to check and use php or something else to query graph : http://graph.facebook.com/[url to check]

Hope it helps! Cheers

Comment: well I already know both solutions but I was asking if it could happen automatically through facebook.